# Automatically set selected date to altField on load

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to set the values of the datepicker field and the `altField` when the page is loaded, and I was wondering if there's an option in the datepicker to do that automatically (i.e. without having to call `setDate`).

I know that if I do something like this:

```
$("#date-div").datepicker({altField:"#date-input",altFormat:"yy-mm-dd", defaultDate:+7});
```

With `date-div` being a `div`, the default date is automatically added to the `date-input` field when the page is loaded.
But if I use a text field instead of a `div` it doesn't set the values automatically (I have to  call `setDate` in a separate line).

I'm just curious about this, I have already implemented it calling setDate, but I would like to know if there's something to do it automatically and if not why? (since it does work when using a div to display the calendar).

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet to set the `defaultDate` is to parse the value of the `altField` with a library like [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), because browser implementations for parsing dates are unreliable. For example, if your `altField` is the field before your datepicker field and it's in ISO 8601 format, you can do this:

```
$(this).datepicker({
    altField: $(this).prev(),
    altFormat: $.datepicker.ISO_8601,
    defaultDate: moment($(this).prev().val()).toDate()
});
```

That will only set the default selected date when opening the calendar. If you also want to populate the datepicker field, you can do this after having initialised the datepicker with the code above:

```
$(this).datepicker("setDate", moment($(this).prev().val()).toDate());
```

Answer (score -2):

Not 100% elegant as it needs repetition but it works for me:

```
$("#date-div").datepicker({altField:"#date-input",altFormat:"yy-mm-dd", defaultDate:$("#date-input").val()});
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't seem to work. Maybe due to differences in format

Comment: -1 this only works if `altFormat` is the same as `dateFormat` ([docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate)).

Comment: if it works under additional condition then why have you downvoted it? I kind of don't understand being punished for giving a solution that works